# Sort list of tuples based on third parameter

Tags: python, operators

My list and what I have think was the right way

```
import operator

my_list = [('green', 'Josef', 22), ('red', 'Marin', 25), ('black', 'Ostoja', 10), ('white', 'Drazen', 11),('purple','Mike',9)]
print (type(my_list))
cpsorted = my_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))
print (cpsorted)
```

But what I got

```
<class 'list'>
None
```

Why?

Comment: `list.sort` returns nothing (i. e. `None`), it sorts `list` object in place

Comment: Chris you need that python gold badge. Go get it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to sort the list in place, you could use `sorted`. Also, you can just use a `lambda` for the key - no need to import anything.

```
my_list = [('green', 'Josef', 22), ('red', 'Marin', 25), ('black', 'Ostoja', 10), ('white', 'Drazen', 11),('purple','Mike',9)]
print (type(my_list))
cpsorted = sorted(my_list, key=lambda tup: tup[2])
print (cpsorted)
```

Answer (score 3):

`list.sort` sorts the list in place. Check `my_list`:

```
>>> my_list
[('purple', 'Mike', 9), ('black', 'Ostoja', 10), ('white', 'Drazen', 11), ('green', 'Josef', 22), ('red', 'Marin', 25)]
>>> help(list.sort)
...
    L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
```

Comment: Alternatively, call `sorted(my_list)` to get the sorted version of `my_list`, without modifying `my_list`.